# Will this work on my laptop?

Tags: intel

I have a laptop with Windows 7 Pro and a Core 2 duo processor. (Lenovo SL510 Laptop) My Lpatop has 6Gb ram. What version of ubuntu do i need? And will it work at all?
P.S. I have integrated graphics...

Answer (score 0):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1467788 <- similar thread with the same laptop in question. Do refer to it.

You can install Ubuntu 64-bit version easily. However, I recommend that you burn a Live CD and use it first to see if all (or most of) your drivers are working. Your laptop has enough RAM. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Ya it should work. And if ubuntu don't work for u. Check out linux  mint. Or opensuse. They are all really good. Just a matter of finding what works for you. 
Hope this helps. Good luck on your task.
Here are some links for u

Mint = http://www.linuxmint.com/download.php

Opensuse = http://www.openSUSE.org

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar computer I suggest downloading 13.04 64 bit and try that.  If that doesn't work try 32 bit.  Hope this helps!! I had similar questions recently too.